# GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

What is the sampling time JVM uses to throw 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded'? 
I know you can control 98% and 2% with parameters GCTimeLimit and GCHeapFreeLimit but whats the sampling time?

Answer (score 82):

From [Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)

the following

> Excessive GC Time and OutOfMemoryError
>
> The concurrent collector will throw an OutOfMemoryError if too much
>   time is being spent in garbage collection: if more than 98% of the
>   total time is spent in  garbage collection and less than 2% of the
>   heap is recovered, an OutOfMemoryError  will be thrown. This feature
>   is designed to prevent applications from running for an extended
>   period of time while making little or no progress because the heap is
>   too small. If necessary, this feature can be disabled by adding the
>   option
>   -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command line.
>
> The policy is the same as that in the parallel collector, except that
>   time spent performing concurrent collections is not counted toward the
>   98% time limit. In other words, only collections performed while the
>   application is stopped count toward excessive GC time. Such
>   collections are typically due to a concurrent mode failure or an
>   explicit collection request (e.g., a call to System.gc()).

in conjunction with a passage further down

> One of the most commonly encountered uses of explicit garbage
>   collection occurs with RMIs distributed garbage collection (DGC).
>   Applications using RMI refer to objects in other virtual machines.
>   Garbage cannot be collected in these distributed applications without
>   occasionally collection the local heap, so RMI forces full collections
>   periodically. The frequency of these collections can be controlled
>   with properties. For example,
>
> ```
> java -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
> ```
>
> `-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000`  specifies explicit collection once per hour instead of the default rate of once per
>   minute. However, this may also cause some objects to take much longer
>   to be reclaimed. These properties can be set as high as Long.MAX_VALUE
>   to make the time between explicit collections effectively infinite, if
>   there is no desire for an upper bound on the timeliness of DGC
>   activity.

Seems to imply that the evaluation period for determining the 98% is one minute long, but it might be configurable on Sun's JVM with the correct define.

Of course, other interpretations are possible.

Comment: RMI distributed garbage collection is an unrelated activity to regular garbage collection.  So I don't see how you can infer what you just did.

Comment: The inference isn't perfect or even correct, that's why "seems to imply" is used instead of "implies".  If you agree with the observation that if the folks over at Sun used one minute in determining the garbage collection interval for RMI, that collection time in concurrent collection is only accumulated calculated when the main program halts, and make a bit of a leap of faith, then odds are good the 98% is collected over one minute.  It's a magic number, but one minute is a magic number often used in comparison to say 3.5 minutes.

Comment: @StephenC do you mean even if we set `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`  it will not impact RMI related configuration and system will invoke gc in frequency set with parameter `-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval`

Comment: @Steephen - No.  That's not what I am saying.  I'm talking about this statement: *"Seems to imply that the evaluation period for determining the 98% is one minute long ..."*.  And note that Edwin agrees that the inference is "imperfect".  The inference is based on the assumption that that the Sun folks who implemented RMI (& DGC) were in close communication with the folks who implemented the GC overhead limit mechanism.  I suspect that the two developments actually happened at different times. Note that the `-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval` property has been around since Java 1.2.

Comment: Anyway, a better approach to finding the real answer to this question would be to look at the OpenJDK source code.