# Travis Maven build exits with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: maven, travis-ci, aspectj-maven-plugin, tycho-surefire-plugin

I have a maven build running on Travis (dockerized) which builds just fine on my command line. Since a couple of days I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` during the test cases. This happens always during the AspectJ test cases.

The output of the last build is https://travis-ci.org/dresden-ocl/dresdenocl/builds/53030457.

I did not made any intensive changes. And I did not touch the AspectJ part of the application. I tested various things with JAVA_OPTS, MAVEN_OPTS and even passing more RAM in the pom.xml for tycho-surefire-plugin. Nothing helped.

How can I get rid of the error and make all my tests run again? I think they changed anything on Travis' side that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201549/travis-ci-ignoring-maven-opts) and references an issue how [Travis CI provides MAVEN_OPTS](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1689). So if you are not fine with provided MAVEN_OPTS values you are not able to build in an containerized environment, because there is no sudo available.

```
before_install: 
  - sudo rm /etc/mavenrc
  - export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=$HOME/.m2/repository -Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=512m"
```

[This pull request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/pull/475) will make your changes to MAVEN_OPTS work. Thus, you can change MAVEN_OPTS without having to use the workaround above and therefore can use containerized builds with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

`GC overhead limit exceeded` means that your JVM is spending the most of the time in garbage collection which indicates some serious problems. This could not be fixed through `JAVA_OPTS` or `MAVEN_OPTS` because this is a programming (code) problem. You can try to add

```
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

but thats not recommended. For further information see [this](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371505/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded).

Comment: How could it be that this was not causing problems for a year and now suddenly always makes the build fail on Travis?

Comment: That's quite difficult to guess without access to code and build enviroment. You should check what changed between clean run and first occur of this exception. Since it within your test: Could it be that your build up a huge test enviroment which executes just a short test? But that's just a guess of me...

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing your stack size, e.g. by `ulimit -s 82768` and re-try. To check the limits, run `ulimit -a` or `free -m` for free memory.