# Travis CI ignoring MAVEN_OPTS?

Tags: scala, maven, travis-ci, scala-maven-plugin

My Scala project (Maven-managed) is failing to build on Travis, throwing a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error despite compiling fine locally with the same `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. I suspect that Travis is somehow ignoring my `MAVEN_OPTS`: When I try to test against Oracle JDK 8, Travis logs:

```
$ Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx3g"
```

which looks good. However, soon after it logs:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
```

which is troubling since NOWHERE am I specifying `-XX:MaxPermSize=192m`, only `512m`. (This leads me to believe my `-Xmx3g` is also being ignored, causing the compilation failure.)

I tried specifying the `MAVEN_OPTS` in many additional places in my pom, to no avail. For example, for the maven-scala-plugin, I have:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <jvmArgs>
    <jvmArg>-Xmx3g</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArg>
  </jvmArgs>
</configuration>
```

And I also have the following under the maven-surefire-plugin and scalatest plugin, though the build is failing during compilation not tests:

```
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
</configuration>
```

The following is the entirety of my .travis.yml:

```
language: java
env:
  global:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx3g"
script: mvn clean install
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
    - oraclejdk7
```

I'm using Scala 2.11.2 and scala-maven-plugin 3.2.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE (11/2/15):**

This was finally fully resolved [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4613#issuecomment-135215956). Quoting:

If you want to use container-based builds (not relying on sudo), you can echo what you want into a `$HOME/.mavenrc` file and that will take precedence over `/etc/mavenrc`, like so:

in `.travis.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - echo "MAVEN_OPTS='-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m'" > ~/.mavenrc
```

(you could also put this in `before_install` depending on your setup).

**Old answer:**

I finally found the answer [here](http://sebastiankirsch.blogspot.com/2014/09/coveralls-for-java-travis-maven-invoker.html), which references [this (closed but not resolved) issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1689) on the Travis CI github.

It seems like Travis exports a `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable as root via the file `/etc/mavenrc`, which then does not get overridden by any other `MAVEN_OPTS` definitions (e.g. via env/global settings in the travis config). The workaround is to delete `/etc/mavenrc` before setting custom `MAVEN_OPTS`.

I was able to set custom `MAVEN_OPTS` and build successfully using the following in my `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
  - sudo rm /etc/mavenrc
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2469m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
  - mvn clean install
```

Note that I am NOT using `language: java` in my travis config, just calling maven directly via the `script` directive.

Comment: You probably want before_install, or before_script, to execute the echo command. You wouldn't want to completely replace script this way.

Comment: @CraigP.Motlin thanks, I think you're right, I edited my answer to use `before_script` rather than just script. In my case it doesn't really matter since I am replacing script anyway in order to compile using both maven and sbt. Could you elaborate on why it's bad to completely replace script?

Comment: It replaces the command which runs tests with the echo command. So the build basically sets the environment and exits. It would be ok if the command was something like echo ... && mvn ...

Comment: Similarly, Alpine Linux's Maven 3 package contains a /etc/mavenrc that sets the `-Xmx` param. There are probably other environments with this problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

`export MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true` is the recommended way of doing this when dealing with a system that has an /etc/mavenrc.  This will make it ignore the defaults and read the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to set `-Xmx3g` in Travis CI builds, its servers have limited memory to be free for JVM heap in forked surefire tests.

Here is project that use `-Xmx2560m` for max speed on Travis CI:
https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/8f22977981e0c4d21b67beee994b339eb787ee9a/pom.xml#L151

You can check available memory by `- sudo cat /proc/meminfo` line added to `.travis.yml`. Here is output from some Travis CI build: https://travis-ci.org/plokhotnyuk/actors/jobs/55013090#L923

If your project requires bigger heap size then try https://www.shippable.com

Or it is better to use Wercker (much faster builds and without waiting in queue at all) http://wercker.com

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I am still getting the same error, and the Java 8 build log is still saying 192m, though with the reduced memory my project still builds fine on my server.

Comment: @emma-strubell, it is possible to share your effective pom? Have you your code open-sourced?

Comment: Yes, the pom is here: https://github.com/strubell/factorie/blob/jflex-tokenization/pom.xml

Comment: In that pom both `maven-surefire-plugin` and `scalatest-maven-plugin` are enabled to run tests, and both of them can be configured with JVM options for forked tests by argLine argument.

Comment: Both plugins have argLine set, is there something else I should specify in the argLine?

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me.

```
language: java
sudo: false
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
install: MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss4M" mvn install -DskipTests=true
script: MAVEN_SKIP_RC=true MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss4M" mvn
```

The MAVEN_SKIP_RC is needed as @adam says and the MAVEN_OPTS are what I needed to get javac to stop blowing out the stack.