# How to set JVM parameter -Xmx for Play Framework 2.1

Tags: java, playframework, jvm

When running my Play App, I often get the following error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` I now want to increase the MaxHeapSize.

First, I applied the parameters to my startup script:

```
cd app_x
.../play/play-2.2.1/play clean compile stage
app_x/target/universal/stage/bin/app_x -J-Xmx3g
```

However, the parameters of the JVM stay the same. htop says 
`java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m ...` for the process.

Then I configured the environment variable:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx3g"
```

I executed `play test` and got:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx3g
```

However, the Xmx parameters of the JVM didn't change either.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Try `stage/bin/genehopper -Xmx3g`. There is also a `-mem` switch that was removed in newer versions... it may work there

Comment: When I try it your way, the following error occurs: Bad application path: -Xmx3g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It finally worked with the follwing parameters

```
/path/to/bin/<project-name> -mem 512 -J-server
```

as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-additional-JVM-arguments

Comment: Same in 2.8.x https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#JVM-configuration

Answer (score 4):

Option 1

Adding below settings to the Build.scala

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx3g", "-Xms3g", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M")
```

Option 2

Add below to the VM options of your running terminal

```
$ JAVA_OPTS="-Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:MetaspaceSize=2048M" ./activator start
```

> -XX:MaxPermSize=92m

This is a default value, and in most cases you don’t need to change it. You may increase it only if you get “OutOfMemoryError” in “PermGen space”. In your case you might have to increase it.

There is still [bugs](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3688) faced by activator module

More information regarding the findings related to the problem
[GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371505/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: @Matthias Munz sorry for the late reply, can you specify where it went wrong!

Comment: hope by now you might have made it work!, if so share your thought about the approach as well!

Comment: I wrote the solution in the post below